# How to add outer gutter to Bourbon Neat's outer-container?

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

On widths smaller than `$max-width`, the grid starts from the edge of the viewport. I added some padding to avoid the text from starting from the edge of the viewport, but now it's out of alignment with the grid. How can I make the grid start from the content edge rather than the viewport please?

[image: mobile grid]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the current version of Neat (1.8). The good news is that in 2.0 this functionality is baked in, it will be released soon but you can download the latest Beta here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat

**UPDATE**

**Neat 2.0** has now been released where this is included, you can find more info here:

http://neat.bourbon.io/

Be warned a lot of the syntax has changed